# What is the password parameter to openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, encryption, parameters

The PHP documentation for the [openssl_encrypt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) functions states

> string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string
>   $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )

**Can somebody help me understand what the argument named `$password` is?**
An answer could include a confirmation or rejection of the idea, that besides named `$password` the parameter indeed is used as the key for the encryption.

What is the password parameter to `openssl_encrypt`? Is it a password string (with only printable characters) or is it a key (with non-prinatable characters and ASCII-Z terminators)?

---

### Explanation

I am stuck with the documention of PHP's [openssl_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). Being a nice guy and trying to do the *"RTM"* I cannot make much sense with the imho unsatisfying documentation.

The problem is that for me there is a difference between a **password** and a **key** when it comes to encryption. A key is directly the *parameter* used for encryption and hence necessarily of a specific size - "the keylength" - i.e. 128/256/512 bits depending on the cipher and keylength desired. A *password* on the other hand is a to my understanding a human readable string entered via the keyboard which may in difference be of any length and which is before being used to encrypt first converted into a *key*.

hence schematic difference:

- password => key => encryption
- key => encryption

Unfortunatelly in the PHP [openssl_encrypt documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) I cannot find any information how to use a *key*. The only thing suggested is a parameter "password".

Can anybody give me a glue how a key can be used? 
Surely I donot want to enter the key as the password parameter as I want a specific *key* to be used in encryption. I do **not** want this *key* to be simply missunderstood as a parameter and serve for another key being calculated from my "key mistaken as password".

Additionally the mistery continues looking at the documention regarding the initialization vector parameter in the same [openssl_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) function. It simply states:

**iv** A non-NULL Initialization Vector.
and that iv should be a string. Given that the iv is normaly a binary data of a certain length and for instance a string terminating \0 (hex 0x00) can be occuring inside I am puzzled what format is desired.

In essence I feel very much left alone with the PHP documentation which also states

> WARNING This function is currently not documented; only its argument
>   list is available.

#### Update

I did some testing, and "trying around" to help me figure out what the *password* parameter is.

using this code:

```
$pass="0123456789abcdefghijklmnob";
$iv="0123456789abcdef";
echo "using $pass results:\n";
echo openssl_encrypt("test secret string", 'aes-128-cbc',  $pass,NULL,$iv);
```

I get this result:

```
using 0123456789abcdefghijklmnob results:
XjEeaLucY38Y6XEUceYMYKTebR4kOp3s727ipMl5KNc=
```

Then changing the length of the "*password*" parameter:

```
$pass="0123456789abcdefg"; //hijklmnob";
$iv="0123456789abcdef";
echo "using $pass results:\n";
echo openssl_encrypt("test secret string", 'aes-128-cbc',  $pass,NULL,$iv);
```

I get still the same encrypted code:

```
using 0123456789abcdefg results:
XjEeaLucY38Y6XEUceYMYKTebR4kOp3s727ipMl5KNc
```

It seems by way of **testing** yet not by way of *being informed by the documentation* that
the password is indeed only considered up to the first 16 bytes which seem to be the 128 bit that would be the key.

It frightens me that in such a sensitive function (used for encryption) the documentation is bad and excessive input of one poorly documented parameter is not even warned about. Also I am quite convinced that *password* should rather be named *key* as it seems those 16 bytes do directly represent the key.

Comment: @noloader *diatribe*? Really? Agreed that I am not happy that the PHP docu is less than perfect her, yet did I use coarse language? Anyways, thanks for suggesting to highlight the question!

Comment: Indeed, the documentation leaves something to be desired. You should file a documentation bug against the project to get it clarified for future readers.

Answer (score 13):

The `$password` parameter is indeed the key. The key size depends on the AES mode you're using (as you know).

As you noted in your update, for AES-128, only the first 16 characters/bytes count for the key. For AES-256, it would be the first 32 characters.

When one uses the `openssl_encrypt()` and `openssl_decrypt()` functions, one can simply pass a 32 character human-readable password for the `$password`/key parameter.

For example, my input for the password parameter might be `$password = "This is 32 characters long......";`

Most people don't like having to write up a plaintext password that is a fixed length, so they might compute a hash and truncate it to the correct length. They would use this hash as their encryption key/password.

For example, I could compute an MD5 hash of a password/phrase of any length that I would like and then use that as my AES password/key:

```
$plaintextPass = 'This is my password. This password is not exactly 32 bytes, but that is okay because I am hashing this.';
$password = hash('md5', $plaintextPass); /* the encryption key */
```

With that in place, no matter what plaintext password I use, I can have a valid 32 character/byte string as my encryption key/password. This does reduce the entropy of the encryption key/password, though, because a normal 32 character string has a larger key space than an MD5 hash output (256 possibilities per byte vs. 16 possibilities per byte); however, 16^32 is still certainly out of the range of brute force.

*Off topic*: In some of my personal programs, I have been working on using 32 randomly generated bytes with values between 0-255. This would make the entropy of the encryption key 256^32 which is infeasible to bruteforce. This will also be resistant to dictionary attacks because the 32-bytes are randomly generated using a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

So, to sum this all up, yes, the `$password` parameter is indeed the key used for encryption. I agree with you that is should be written as `$key` in the documentation, but oh well. The password/key which you select for encryption can be humanly readable as long as it satisfies the length requirements of the hashing key. To satisfy these length requirements, one can hash a human-readable/plaintext password and use the hash of that password as the key (`$password` parameter), but the human-readable password should still be long and unique.

The documentation is not very clear, however [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#104438) on the `openssl_encrypt()` PHP doc page really helped me when I was trying to understand the function. The comment provides an example as well as useful information. To direct quote the author of the comment:

> Because the password parameter documented here is not the password.
>   ...
>   It is the key!
>   [Comment minorly edited]

Comment: You can do `$password = hex2bin(hash('md5', $plaintextPass))` to convert the hex output of the hash to plain binary. That way you can actually use all 256 possibilities per byte (just don't expect the password to be human-readable)... 16^32 is still huge, but, doing this is simple and it can't hurt!

Comment: @Jojodmo, good point and, in fact, I believe you could do `$password = hash('md5', $plainPass, true)` to get the same result with one less method call, since that would set the [hash function's](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) `$raw_output` parameter to true. That being said, if I was implementing a solution nowadays (having learned a bit more than I knew six years ago), I would look at changing this implementation to use a password-based key derivation function, such as PHP's [hash_pbkdf2 function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php), with raw output.

Comment: Anyone know what happens when you use a password with the length less than 32 bytes for AES-256 mode? It seems to work, but I want to know what the function does to get its full 32 byte key.

Comment: @Peter, I might be misinterpreting the code, but at a cursory glance, it looks like OpenSSL will zero-pad your password. (See [PHP's OpenSSL extension code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4522cbb789ea4d0b70b5a1bdf7f3c0f4648d8fb7/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L7032).) It looks like when the password's length is less than the key size, the library allocates a zero-filled buffer and then copies in whatever password characters were provided. Again, though, I only gave it a cursory glance.

Comment: @SpencerD actually the above answer pointed me in the right direction. From my code, I thought I had allocated a key with less length, but I was confusing alphabetical characters with hex, thus I have a 60 character-long string key, which was being truncated to the first 32 characters (luckily) :-D